# laptop screen broken, using monitor. started in minimal safe mode, can't see anything

Tags: display, safe-mode

neither my monitor nor tv screen recognizes the signal from my laptop since I booted in safe mode.

I can't see anything on the screen so I can't possibly follow any instructions that would require me to click on anything.

I could only enter a combination of keyboard inputs blindly.

What are my options?  Using Windows 8.1

Comment: Are you still getting any output during POST, or does the screen remain black all the time?

Comment: No output at all

Comment: Im thinking there must be some tool/program it uses to send the signal to the monitor but it doesnt load the tool in safe mode.  There must be some combo of keys I can press to run that tool; or combo of keys I can press to make it boot the same way that it was before.

Comment: Not exactly a tool, but drivers. The graphics drivers that support other video outputs are not loaded in safe mode.

Comment: Alright then, any way to load the drivers if I cant see anything?